# JTree - how to add nodes with a For-Loop?

Tags: java, swing, loops, jtree

I have a simple `JTree`, that systematically adds nodes from relevant vars:

```
public void init()
{   
    final String section1 = "JAVA";

    final String section1_content1 = "Tutorial1";
    final String section1_content2 = "Tutorial2";
    final String section1_content3 = "Tutorial3";
    final String section1_content4 = "Tutorial4";
    final String section1_content5 = "Tutorial5";
    final String section1_content6 = "Tutorial6";

    final String content1a = "Introduction";
    final String content1b = "Hello World!";

    // Create the title node:
    title = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(section1);

    // Create and attach the 1st subtree:
    selection = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(section1_content1);

    selection.insert(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(content1a),0);
    selection.insert(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(content1b),0);

    title.insert(selection,0);
}
```

what I would like, is to use a For-Loop, to avoid extra selection.inserts

something like

```
String[] sections = new String[]{ "Tutorial1", "Tutorial2", "Tutorial3", "Tutorial4", "Tutorial5", "Tutorial6" };

for (int i=0; i < sections.length; i++) { 
    selection = new DefaultMutableTreeNode( sections[i] );
}
```

How would I do this?

thanks

Comment: see [Oracle tutorila How to use Tree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) there is described basic stuff about

Comment: thank you, I have examined the examples prior to this question, and am aware that nodes are added individually

Comment: .. I'm sure there will be a way to add all the nodes with just a few lines of code, so if anyone has ideas they would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: good, the same nodes is possible to add from loop and iterating in prepared arrays of Objects, there isn't difference, your idea is right and correct

Comment: don't understand the problem: as long as you have the data to insert in some datastructure (any collection will do), simply iterate, create nodes and add them (beware: once you created the model, you must add the nodes using _model_ api, otherwise the changes won't show up!)

Answer (score 0):

You could put all of the values into an enum and iterate through that instead.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple:

```
    for (int i=0; i<sections.length; i++) {
    selection = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(( sections[i]));
    title.insert(selection,0);
    }
```

sections[i] needs double brackets