# JTree For-Loop Array Syntax

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, jtree

Having difficulty with the syntax of a for loop, that reads data from an array and adds it to a `JTree`.

```
public void init()
{   final String section1 = "JAVA";
    String[] sections = new String[]{ "Tutorial6", "Tutorial5", "Tutorial4", "Tutorial3", "Tutorial2", "Tutorial1" };

String contents[][] = {
        {"content1a", "content1b"},
        {"content2a", "content2b"},
        {"content3a", "content3b"}
    };  

    title = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(section1);

    for (int i=0; i<sections.length; i++)
    {   selection = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(( sections[i]));

        selection.insert(new DefaultMutableTreeNode((contents[i])),0);



        //title.insert(selection,0);
    }
```

Adding the sections works ok, but adding nodes to those sections is the issue. How would I get the for loop to work so that nodes with the content name is added to the relevant section when parsing the for-loop ??

this is the code that is not working:

```
    selection.insert(new DefaultMutableTreeNode((contents[i])),0);
```

Thanks !!

Comment: Please clarify how this differs from your previous question on the same topic: [JTree - how to add nodes with a For-Loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752099/jtree-how-to-add-nodes-with-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 1):

Creating a TreeNode is really one single node. So passing an array to the node constructor won't create a whole list of nodes. In order to achieve what you want, add a nested for loop.

```
String contents[][] =
{
    {"content1a", "content1b"},
    {"content2a", "content2b"},
    {"content3a", "content3b"}
};  

title = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(section1);

for (int i=0; i < sections.length; i++)
{
    selection = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(sections[i]);
    for (int k = 0; k < contents[i].length; ++k)
    {
        selection.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(contents[i][k]));
    }
    title.add(selection);
}
```

Comment: Yes, almost. Your mistake is content[i] instead of the correct content[i][j].

Comment: I have an ArrayOutOfBoundsException :/

Comment: Fixed !! contents String needs 6 sets of values. Thanks again Martijn :)

Comment: Ah, yes, indeed. You are right. I didn't see that. But my answer was right as well. So you can accept my answer by clicking the tick under my score.